# github actions delete event does not trigger my workflow

Tags: github, github-actions

I create a new branch off of the main branch.

Then add this workflow

```
name: test

on:
  delete:
  push:

jobs:
  test:
    name: test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: echo
        run: echo ${{ github.event_name }}
```

then push the code. it triggers the pipeline and returns "push"

Then I go to the branches tab in the GitHub UI and delete this branch. The workflow does not gets triggered.

How can I trigger a workflow on a delete event? I want to use this to delete some deployment resources after deleting a branch.

Comment: I think I found the answer to the question.
"Note: This event will only trigger a workflow run if the workflow file is on the default branch."

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#delete